# Проблема с указанием маршрута в Route::resource

Tags: php, laravel

Здравствуйте , я создал путь `Route::resource();`
Там все прописал как положено.
Мне нужно, чтобы в blade по клику переходило на статью выбраную.
Я пробовал вот так:
`<a href="{{  route('articles.show/id',['id'=>$article->article_id])  }}">`

И в итоге выдает ошибку **`Route [articles.show/id] not defined.`**

Подскажите, как мне правильно указать маршрут?
Вот к примеру, я когда делал **без** `Route:resource()`, у меня вот так все работало

`<a href="{{  route('articles/id',['id'=>$article->article_id])  }}">`

```
//articles - заданный Route Name само собой.
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хорошо бы увидеть route, но вообще должно работать так:

```
<a href="{{ route('articles.show', ['id' => $article->article_id]) }}">
```

Comment: Столько перемучился, оказывалось просто id надо было убрать. Благодарю

Answer (score 0):

```
{{route('articles.show')}}/{{$article->article_id}}
```

Попробуйте сделать таким способом

Comment: Отформатируйте хотя бы.